# installing a package on SQL machine learning services with sqlmlutils gives an error

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to install packages in an SQL server instance with ML services installed. I need an updated version of pandas to be able to load api data into a database.
The pandas version that is installed does not support the `json_normalize()` function.

I run my code with visual code and Python 3.7.1 kernel which is the same version as the SQL server Python version.

```
import sqlmlutils
import os

os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://proxy:8080'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://proxy:8080'


connection = sqlmlutils.ConnectionInfo(server="server", database="database")

sqlmlutils.SQLPackageManager(connection).install("numpy", upgrade = True)
```

I also tried using a local file as was mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/package-management/install-additional-python-packages-on-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

But nothing really works, and the error I am getting is not very helpful.

What can I do to fix or further debug this issue?

I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]A \'Python\' script error occurred during execution of \'sp_execute_external_script\' with HRESULT 0x80004004. (39004) (SQLMoreResults); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]An external script error occurred: 

Error in execution. Check the output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 5, in 
  File "C:\\ProgramData\\MSSQLSERVER\\Temp-PY\\Appcontainer1\\0D620A3B-DD4E-48F5-A589-28E99D241708\\sqlindb_0.py", line 60, in transform
    assert package_exists_in_scope("numpy", "public") != False
AssertionError

SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution. Check the output for more information. (39019); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]STDOUT message(s) from external script: 

Express Edition will continue to be enforced.
SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\\PYTHON_SERVICES\\lib\\site-packages\\revoscalepy\\computecontext\\RxInSqlServer.py", line 605, in rx_sql_satellite_call
    rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)
  File "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\\PYTHON_SERVICES\\lib\\site-packages\\revoscalepy\\RxSerializable.py", line 375, in rx_native_call
    ret = px_call(functionname, params)
RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed. (39005)')
```